# How to encrypt and decrypt URl parameter in java?

Tags: java, spring, encryption, spring-security

How to encrypt and decrypt URl parameter in java without having the html characters like '/,&,=?'

```
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEParameterSpec;

public class DesEncrypter {

    Cipher ecipher;
    Cipher dcipher;

    byte[] salt =  {
            (byte)0xA9, (byte)0x9B, (byte)0xC8, (byte)0x32,
            (byte)0x56, (byte)0x35, (byte)0xE3, (byte)0x03
        };

    int iterationCount = 3;

    public DesEncrypter(String passPhrase) {

        try{

            KeySpec keySpec = new PBEKeySpec(passPhrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterationCount);
            SecretKey key = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBEWithMD5AndDES").generateSecret(keySpec);

            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());

            AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new PBEParameterSpec(salt, iterationCount);

            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, paramSpec);

        } catch (java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e){
        } catch (java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException e){
        } catch (javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException e){
        } catch (java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        } catch (java.security.InvalidKeyException e){
        }
    }

    public String encrypt(String str){

        try{

            byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
            byte[] enc  = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);

            return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);

        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e){
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e){
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        }

        return null;
    }

    public String decrypt(String str){

        try{

            byte[] dec = new sun.misc.BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(str);
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);

            return new String(utf8,"UTF8");

        } catch (javax.crypto.BadPaddingException e){
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e){
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        } catch (java.io.IOException e){
        }

        return null;
    }

}
```

My Code is as above and i am getting encrypted result:6puu4YjzScxHsv9tI/N92g==
In the above output due to backslash i am getting the error that i want to avoid.

Comment: That's a really bad idea. Can you tell us **why** you want to encrypt them? You *either* want to use TLS to encrypt the whole communication between server and client or not give out the information that should be secret in the first place.

Comment: Oh boy! Don't write empty `catch` blocks, ever! Your method will just return `null` and you'll have **no idea** what went wrong! Put `e.printStackTrace()` there **at least!**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of

```
        byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes("UTF8");
        byte[] enc  = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
        return new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(enc);
```

Use [Apache Commons URL Safe 64 bit encoder](http://commons.apache.org/codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Base64.html#encodeBase64URLSafeString%28byte[]%29) to encode after encryption.

```
Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(enc);
```

To decode before descryption:

```
Base64.decodeBase64(dec)
```

Please Note this is **ENCODER** not encryptor. But the String  is URL safe.

---

Ideally, you should always Encode your URL using [URL Encoder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which will ensure that special characters are encoded. So, even if you are having a URL with restricted characters, it will be safe.

Comment: I can't imagine why this answer was marked as correct. OP requested encryption, not better base64-encoding.

Comment: @EJP -- you should read the question and the answer more carefully. The encryption results Byte array. When OP encodes in 64-base it returns String equivalent that's not safe for URL. He wanted a technique to safely convert to Base64. I know the difference between encoding and encryption. And I mentioned it in the answer. The OP is misleading. You should better see the revisions of the question where I edited. But when updated the question, I realized he need a safe encoding. It does not justify a down-vote.

Comment: The issue here is whether *you* read the question. It is about encryption. He is *already* base64-encoding the result. All you have shown here is another way to do that. It does not answer his original question. And decodeBase64() does not decrypt, contrary to what you have written above.

Comment: @EJP "He is already base64-encoding the result" -- yeah, and that's the problem. The result is not safe for URL! He either need to encode URL using URLEncoder or convert the encrypted Byte array to URL safe String. And that's where my solution comes in. And, I agree the _decrypt_ that's mentioned in the answer was in context as "before decrypting do the following" but since I have not mentioned the context. _Descrypt_ is misfit.